algorithm for undoing Bresenham lines
I have a blob of points on a grid that I want to create a sensible polygon outline for. The points will be selected by the user so I can't expect them to be perfectly following Bresenham's algorithm for lines with weird slopes. However, I am still struggling to even get something working for an obvious "nice" sloped side:
#
###
#####
#######
#####
###
#

What I want is to turn those points into an SVG polygon (or path, or polyline, etc). It is supposed to be a nice neat triangle as you might expect.
Here is the code I have tried so far:
import cmath

s = """
#
###
#####
#######
#####
###
#
"""
pts = [complex(c, r)
       for (r, rt) in enumerate(s.splitlines())
       for (c, ch) in enumerate(rt)
       if ch == "#"]


def centroid(pts: list[complex]) -> complex:
    return sum(pts) / len(pts)


def sort_counterclockwise(pts: list[complex],
                          center: complex | None = None) -> list[complex]:
    if center is None:
        center = centroid(pts)
    return sorted(pts, key=lambda p: cmath.phase(p - center))


def perimeter(pts: list[complex]) -> list[complex]:
    out = []
    for pt in pts:
        for d in (-1, 1, -1j, 1j, -1+1j, 1+1j, -1-1j, 1-1j):
            xp = pt + d
            if xp not in pts:
                out.append(pt)
                break
    return sort_counterclockwise(out, centroid(pts))


def example(all_points: list[complex], scale: float = 20) -> str:
    p = perimeter(all_points)
    p.append(p[0])
    vbx = max(map(lambda x: x.real, p)) + 1
    vby = max(map(lambda x: x.imag, p)) + 1
    return f"""<svg
    viewBox="-1 -1 {vbx} {vby}"
    width="{vbx * scale}"
    height="{vbx * scale}">
    <polyline
    fill="none"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="0.1"
    points="{" ".join(map(lambda x: f"{x.real},{x.imag}", p))}">
    </polyline></svg>"""


print(example(pts))

It results in a horrible jagged mess:


<svg
    viewBox="-1 -1 7.0 8.0"
    width="140.0"
    height="140.0">
    <polyline
    fill="none"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="0.1"
    points="0.0,3.0 0.0,2.0 0.0,1.0 1.0,2.0 2.0,2.0 2.0,3.0 3.0,3.0 4.0,3.0 4.0,4.0 5.0,4.0 6.0,4.0 4.0,5.0 3.0,5.0 2.0,5.0 2.0,6.0 1.0,6.0 0.0,7.0 0.0,6.0 0.0,5.0 0.0,4.0 0.0,3.0">
    </polyline></svg>



Any tips on making the algorithm respond better to making clearly-defined slopes and only produce a triangle for this?
EDIT: Here is another test triangle, with mostly-vertical lines:
#
#
#
##
##
##
###
##
##
##
#
#
#

And here is one with both simultaneously (not a triangle, obviously):
#
#
#
##
##
##
###
######
#########
######
###
##
##
##
#
#
#

